# Modifying SwipeViewController Pod to run in a ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm using this pod 'SwipeViewController' (https://github.com/fortmarek/SwipeViewController) that really gives me the effect that I want but the problem is that it only runs as the main navigation controller and I want it to work in a container view because I want to use it for this social app in the profile menu like twitter does with "My Tweets", "Likes", "Repost"...

so for example I need this...

https://camo.githubusercontent.com/f4eb2a8ba0a11e672d02a1ef600e62b5272a7843/687474703a2f2f696d6775722e636f6d2f5344496b6634622e676966

to work in here:
[image: Img 1]
[image: Img 2]

So just an explanation, to make the pod work you need to add this line of code to the appDelegate

```
let pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
let navigationController = YourViewControllerName(rootViewController: pageController)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

which creates a new window with the SwipeController, I need a way to make it work in a View controller.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar last night using the tutorial here:

https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

My associated code is below.  I created an IBOutlet from the container view to my ViewController and then the code below adds the appropriate view controller to the container view depending on the setting of my `Bool` called `buttonDefault`. Make sure to add the child view to your container view and not the main view from the view controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

 // MARK: Container View
// https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/
lazy var remoteViewController: RemoteViewController = {
    // Load Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)

    // Instantiate View Controller
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RemoteViewController") as! RemoteViewController

    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()

lazy var gestureRemoteViewController: GestureRemoteViewController = {
    // Load Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)

    // Instantiate View Controller
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GestureRemoteViewController") as! GestureRemoteViewController

    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()

func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Add Child View Controller
    addChildViewController(viewController)

    // Add Child View as Subview
    containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)

    // Configure Child View
    viewController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

    // Remove Child View From Superview
    viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
}

func updateView() {
    let settings = Settings()

    if settings.buttonDefault {
        remove(asChildViewController: gestureRemoteViewController)
        add(asChildViewController: remoteViewController)
    } else {
        remove(asChildViewController: remoteViewController)
        add(asChildViewController: gestureRemoteViewController)
    }
}
```

Once you add this just call `updateView()` in your `viewDidLoad` and any time the user selects a new option to view.

I hope this helps.